# Fixing android error "Invalid layout param"

Tags: android

Hey Im fairly new to android programming and I have several errors in my code. I know there were similar errors i searched for it but none particular to my specific code.

The specific lines with its particular errors are as follows:

android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"-Invalid layout param in a Editext:layout_align_left

android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"-Invalid layout param in a Editext:layout_below

android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"-Invalid layout param in a Editext:
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-Invalid layout param in a Editext:

Here is all of my code,please tell me what part I need to correct to fix the error.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.discountprice2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="text|number" >

        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/calc" />
    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had it in relative layout before and it had the same error that's why i changed it to linear layout i thought that would fix the problem but it didnt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `android:layout_alignLeft`, `android:layout_below`, etc. are only bounded to the `RelativeLayout` not in `LinearLayout`, LinearLayout has only two orientation which is vertical and horizontal it does not support layout alignment for each Views.

**solution:**

change your parent layout to `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.discountprice2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

         /////////YOUR CONTENT HERE///////////////

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: I had it in relative layout before and it had the same error that's why i changed it to linear layout i thought that would fix the problem but it didnt.

Comment: @KharlMccatty It is working fine on my eclipse, try clean and build

Comment: @KharlMccatty check my answer, there's problem with your first edittext. You have not closed it properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solutions** ::

1. Change your `Linear layout` to `relative layout`
2. Remove the invalid params from the design if you need `linear
   layout`

***Note*** :: Always clean and build your project if you still see the errors

Answer (score 1):

The following are not the attributes of `LinearLayout`, they belong to `RelativeLayout`

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"

android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"


android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"


android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Change your main layout to `ReativeLayout`

Please go through [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) and [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

**EDIT**

Replace

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"
android:inputType="text|number" >

    <EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/edit_message1"
android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:onClick="sendMessage"
android:text="@string/calc" />
</EditText>
```

with

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"
android:inputType="text|number" >
</EditText>
    <EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/edit_message1"
android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:onClick="sendMessage"
android:text="@string/calc" />
```

Your first `EditText` ended at the last, i.e. after `Button`. It should be closed like above.

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout instead of Linear Layout

Comment: I had it in relative layout before and it had the same error that's why i changed it to linear layout i thought that would fix the problem but it didnt

Answer (score 0):

`layout_alignLeft` makes the left edge of your view match the left edge of the view whose ID you use as the parameters.

`layout_toLeftOf` makes your view placed to the left side of the view whose ID you use (the right edge will be aligned with the left edge of the other view).

For other relative layout params visit here :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

The parameters you have used are for relative layout and not Linear Layout. Change Linear layout to Relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Leadlayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:id="@+id/Leadbutton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="saveButton"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:id="@+id/Leadbutton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/oval"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="clearButton"
            android:text="CLEAR"
            android:textColor="@color/colorblue"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```